# Cant get the price, name and amount from a website

Tags: c#, html, list

How would I get the name, price and volume/amount of these listings.
I need to put each in their own list afterwards. So I guess I also need some kind of for each loop

These are 3 items I can get a list with 100 items but for this example I only got 3.

```
<root>  <div class="market_listing_table_header">
        <div class="market_listing_price_listings_block">
            <div class="market_listing_right_cell market_listing_their_price market_sortable_column" data-sorttype="price">PRICE<span class="market_sort_arrow" style="display:none;"></span></div>
            <div class="market_listing_right_cell market_listing_num_listings market_sortable_column" data-sorttype="quantity">QUANTITY<span class="market_sort_arrow" style="display:none;"></span></div>
            <div class="market_listing_right_cell market_listing_price_listings_combined market_sortable_column" data-sorttype="price">PRICE<span class="market_sort_arrow" style="display:none;"></span></div>
        </div>
                <div class="market_sortable_column" data-sorttype="name"><span class="market_listing_header_namespacer"></span>NAME<span class="market_sort_arrow" style="display:none;"></span></div>
    </div>

<a class="market_listing_row_link" href="http://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/P250%20%7C%20Sand%20Dune%20%28Field-Tested%29" id="resultlink_0">
    <div class="market_listing_row market_recent_listing_row market_listing_searchresult" id="result_0">
                <img id="result_0_image" src="http://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXH5ApeO4YmlhxYQknCRvCo04DEVlxkKgpopujwezhz3MzbcDNG09GzkImemrmkMeuEzjwB7sMgjL_H8d6hilbs_0c5Ym6lI9WddVc2MgyB-FXtl7q6m9bi65jdplfl/62fx62f" srcset="http://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXH5ApeO4YmlhxYQknCRvCo04DEVlxkKgpopujwezhz3MzbcDNG09GzkImemrmkMeuEzjwB7sMgjL_H8d6hilbs_0c5Ym6lI9WddVc2MgyB-FXtl7q6m9bi65jdplfl/62fx62f 1x, http://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXH5ApeO4YmlhxYQknCRvCo04DEVlxkKgpopujwezhz3MzbcDNG09GzkImemrmkMeuEzjwB7sMgjL_H8d6hilbs_0c5Ym6lI9WddVc2MgyB-FXtl7q6m9bi65jdplfl/62fx62fdpx2x 2x"" style="border-color: #D2D2D2;" class="market_listing_item_img" alt="" />       
                <div class="market_listing_price_listings_block">
            <div class="market_listing_right_cell market_listing_num_listings">
                <span class="market_table_value">
                    <span class="market_listing_num_listings_qty">41,449</span>
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="market_listing_right_cell market_listing_their_price">
                <span class="market_table_value">
                    Starting at:<br/>
                    <span style="color:white">$0.03 USD</span>
                </span>
                <span class="market_arrow_down" style="display: none"></span>
                <span class="market_arrow_up" style="display: none"></span>
            </div>
        </div>

                <div class="market_listing_item_name_block">
            <span id="result_0_name" class="market_listing_item_name" style="color: #D2D2D2;">P250 | Sand Dune (Field-Tested)</span>
            <br/>
            <span class="market_listing_game_name">Counter-Strike: Global Offensive</span>
        </div>
        <div style="clear: both"></div>
    </div>
</a>

<a class="market_listing_row_link" href="http://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/Operation%20Breakout%20Weapon%20Case" id="resultlink_1">
    <div class="market_listing_row market_recent_listing_row market_listing_searchresult" id="result_1">
                <img id="result_1_image" src="http://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXU5A1PIYQNqhpOSV-fRPasw8rsUFJ5KBFZv668FFMu1aPMI24auITjxteJwPXxY72AkGgIvZAniLjHpon2jlbl-kpvNjz3JJjVLFG9rl1YLQ/62fx62f" srcset="http://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXU5A1PIYQNqhpOSV-fRPasw8rsUFJ5KBFZv668FFMu1aPMI24auITjxteJwPXxY72AkGgIvZAniLjHpon2jlbl-kpvNjz3JJjVLFG9rl1YLQ/62fx62f 1x, http://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXU5A1PIYQNqhpOSV-fRPasw8rsUFJ5KBFZv668FFMu1aPMI24auITjxteJwPXxY72AkGgIvZAniLjHpon2jlbl-kpvNjz3JJjVLFG9rl1YLQ/62fx62fdpx2x 2x"" style="border-color: #D2D2D2;" class="market_listing_item_img" alt="" />     
                <div class="market_listing_price_listings_block">
            <div class="market_listing_right_cell market_listing_num_listings">
                <span class="market_table_value">
                    <span class="market_listing_num_listings_qty">2,594,132</span>
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="market_listing_right_cell market_listing_their_price">
                <span class="market_table_value">
                    Starting at:<br/>
                    <span style="color:white">$0.03 USD</span>
                </span>
                <span class="market_arrow_down" style="display: none"></span>
                <span class="market_arrow_up" style="display: none"></span>
            </div>
        </div>

                <div class="market_listing_item_name_block">
            <span id="result_1_name" class="market_listing_item_name" style="color: #D2D2D2;">Operation Breakout Weapon Case</span>
            <br/>
            <span class="market_listing_game_name">Counter-Strike: Global Offensive</span>
        </div>
        <div style="clear: both"></div>
    </div>
</a>

<a class="market_listing_row_link" href="http://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/MP7%20%7C%20Army%20Recon%20%28Field-Tested%29" id="resultlink_2">
    <div class="market_listing_row market_recent_listing_row market_listing_searchresult" id="result_2">
                <img id="result_2_image" src="http://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXH5ApeO4YmlhxYQknCRvCo04DEVlxkKgpou6ryFBRw7ODYYzxb092kmZm0mvLwOq7c2GgAuMEpjLqY89mt3wzsr0RpZDygI4PAdQ42MgrS81bqk7u818C8tcjXiSw08qBOp-g/62fx62f" srcset="http://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXH5ApeO4YmlhxYQknCRvCo04DEVlxkKgpou6ryFBRw7ODYYzxb092kmZm0mvLwOq7c2GgAuMEpjLqY89mt3wzsr0RpZDygI4PAdQ42MgrS81bqk7u818C8tcjXiSw08qBOp-g/62fx62f 1x, http://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXH5ApeO4YmlhxYQknCRvCo04DEVlxkKgpou6ryFBRw7ODYYzxb092kmZm0mvLwOq7c2GgAuMEpjLqY89mt3wzsr0RpZDygI4PAdQ42MgrS81bqk7u818C8tcjXiSw08qBOp-g/62fx62fdpx2x 2x"" style="border-color: #D2D2D2;" class="market_listing_item_img" alt="" />      
                <div class="market_listing_price_listings_block">
            <div class="market_listing_right_cell market_listing_num_listings">
                <span class="market_table_value">
                    <span class="market_listing_num_listings_qty">53,539</span>
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="market_listing_right_cell market_listing_their_price">
                <span class="market_table_value">
                    Starting at:<br/>
                    <span style="color:white">$0.03 USD</span>
                </span>
                <span class="market_arrow_down" style="display: none"></span>
                <span class="market_arrow_up" style="display: none"></span>
            </div>
        </div>

                <div class="market_listing_item_name_block">
            <span id="result_2_name" class="market_listing_item_name" style="color: #D2D2D2;">MP7 | Army Recon (Field-Tested)</span>
            <br/>
            <span class="market_listing_game_name">Counter-Strike: Global Offensive</span>
        </div>
        <div style="clear: both"></div>
    </div>
</a>
</root>
```

I have tried this and cant come up with any other way.

```
                XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
                document.LoadXml(System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(data));
                XmlNode rootnode = document.SelectSingleNode("root");
                XmlNodeList items = rootnode.SelectNodes("./a/div");
                foreach (XmlNode node in items)
                {
                    string value = node.SelectSingleNode("./div[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' market_listing_their_price ')]/span/span").InnerText;
                    string num = node.SelectSingleNode("./div[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' market_listing_num_listings ')]/span/span").InnerText;
                    string name = node.SelectSingleNode("./div/span[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' market_listing_item_name ')]").InnerText;
                    valueList.Add(value); //Lowest price for the item
                    numList.Add(num); //Volume of that item
                    nameList.Add(name); //Name of that item
                }
```

Data is the data from the first box of code.
It fails at `document.LoadXml(System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(data));` and I can not see why and I don't know what I do wrong.

Edit:
Now I have come up with this code but it does not work, any suggestions on what to do?

```
                HtmlDocument node = new HtmlDocument();
                node.Load(data);
                valueList = node.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("./div[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' market_listing_their_price ')]/span/span")
                                .Select(p => p.InnerText)
                                .ToList();
                numList = node.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("./div[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' market_listing_num_listings ')]/span/span")
                                .Select(p => p.InnerText)
                                .ToList();
                nameList = node.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("./div/span[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' market_listing_item_name ')]")
                                .Select(p => p.InnerText)
                                .ToList();
                //valueList.Add(value); //Lowest price for the item
                //numList.Add(num); //Volume of that item
                //nameList.Add(name); //Name of that item
```

Comment: This sounds like something suited to the [HTML Agility pack](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

Comment: I already tried using the HTMLAgilityPack. And I could not get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

Here is modified first approach with correct XPath

```
        var valueList = new List<string>();
        var numList = new List<string>();
        var nameList = new List<string>();
        XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
        document.LoadXml(System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(Resource1.New_Text_Document));
        XmlNode rootnode = document.SelectSingleNode("root");
        XmlNodeList items = rootnode.SelectNodes("./a/div");
        foreach (XmlNode node in items)
        {
            string value = node.SelectSingleNode("//div[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), 'market_listing_their_price')]/span/span").InnerText;
            string num = node.SelectSingleNode("//div[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' market_listing_num_listings ')]/span/span").InnerText;
            string name = node.SelectSingleNode("//span[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' market_listing_item_name ')]").InnerText;
            valueList.Add(value); //Lowest price for the item
            numList.Add(num); //Volume of that item
            nameList.Add(name); //Name of that item
        }
```

Comment: What does the Resource1 do? It wont work. Or do I just need to replace it?

Comment: Yes, just replace it with  data

Comment: Still the same problem.. At document.LoadXml(System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(data));                                                                             An unhandled exception of type 'System.Xml.XmlException' occurred in System.Xml.dll

Additional information: Et navn kan ikke begynde med tegnet '"', hexadecimal værdi 0x22. linje 12, position 842.

Comment: Ah yeah, forgot to mention that you have doubled quotes in img src (dpx2x 2x"" )

Comment: Ok, so now I know the problem. But how would I be able to make it not care about it or should I try to get rid of the double ""?

Comment: If you treat it as xml you should have well-formed structure without such errors. Probably HTMLAgilityPack can ignore such errors but I'm not sure

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95564/discussion-between-martin-t-and-akmed0zmey).